# Git : fatal: exec hooks/post-receive failed

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

I have a remote created with `git --bare init`.

When I push I get:

```
Delta compression using up to 2 threads. 
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done. 
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 368 bytes, done. 
Total 4 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

fatal: exec hooks/post-receive failed.
error: hooks/post-receive exited with error code 128
```

hooks/post-receive looks like this:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 git checkout -f
```

The working tree is set in the remote config (path is fine, if I cd into the remote and do `git checkout -f` it checks out into the worktree).

the perms on the hook look like:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 my-user git 28 Sep 20  2010 my.git/hooks/post-receive
```

Any clues as to why the hook may be failing?

Comment: Git forwards output of the hook. Since it didn't forward anything, it seems that the script didn't start at all. Check whether you can run it by hand and check that git is not getting some strange value in `SHELL` environment variable (I am not sure whether it uses it in this case, but in some it does).

Comment: How do I run it by hand?

Comment: I don't get it, why isn't your remote a bare repository?

Comment: @fge I guess he has set `core.worktree`. I don't know if that's the right way to do a repo with different working tree. Possibly it should be a normal repo (not bare) with `core.worktree` set before doing checkout?

Comment: @Ronn: to run it by hand, change into `my.git/hooks/post-receive` and try `./post-receive`.  (To more accurately mimic the environment that the hook runs in, you could do `GIT_DIR=. ./post-receive` instead.)

Answer (score 1):

@Mark Longair and @Jan Hudec, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

I command Z'd out of cat when creating the post-receive hook, the cat process still had that file open.

So, I killed that process and I'm back in business. Thanks